# Magento 1.9 : PayPal Payment Information in Order View

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-express

I placed an order using PayPal express checkout when I try to view it from backend it didn't show payment method PayPal. Can anyone help me?
[image: PayPal Method not showing]

Answer (score 0):

> One of the possible solution which I go through

One of community member also faced the same issue in Magento version 1.9. If you change your password in paypal after setting up Magento and it has special characters, Magento fails to update it in payment method configuration. Removing special characters "fixed" the problem.

Reference: https://community.magento.com/t5/Payments-PayPal/Payment-Information-for-Credit-Card-not-displaying-during/m-p/15943

**I hope this will help**

Comment: I didn't change my password and currently, it has no special characters. Secondly, Magento storing PayPal as a payment method in DB against Order, I verify this programmatically, but Magento not showing it here.

Comment: That's why I said in my answer, one of the possible cause and solution, there may be others as well. So keep coding :) thanks :)